# How to accept a nullable Long in an API endpoint?

Tags: java, reactjs, api, resources

Essentially, I have the following use case: I have an `Entity`, and need to update one of its fields. The field is a `Long`, and it *CAN* be `null` (basically, when I remove the entity I need to `null` out that field). We'll refer to this field as `relativeId`.

My React resource looks like this:

```js
updateEntityField(entityId, relativeId) {
  return req({
    method: 'PUT',
    url: `stuff/entities/${entityId}/relative`,
    data: relativeId,
  });
},
```

And my Java resource look like this:

```java
@ApiOperation("Updates an entity's relative id")
@PUT
@Path("/{id}/relative")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public ApiResult<Arrest> updateRelativeId(
  @ApiParam(value = "Entity id", required = true) @PathParam("id") long entityId,
  @ApiParam(value = "relative id", required = true) @Nullable Long relativeId)
    {
        ...
    }
```

The relativeId is **always** `null` even if it's not `null` on the FE. I've never dealt with passing data that wasn't an object with multiple fields before, so I'm not sure what to do here. Ideally the `relativeId` can just be a path param, but it's difficult to pass null values through there. And I want to keep the resource simple, so I'm trying to avoid things like deliberately passing a `-1`, and then making that `null` when it's accepted in the BE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the @QueryParam annotation, to read this optional value from request query param (also recommend updating the Swagger ApiParam to not be required):

```
@ApiParam(value = "relative id", required = false) @QueryParam @Nullable Long relativeId)
```

Then update the React code to pass it as a query param:

```
updateEntityField(entityId, relativeId) {
    return req({
        method: 'PUT',
        url: `stuff/entities/${entityId}/relative?relativeId=${relativeId}`
    });
},
```